# making a div stick at the bottom on container div show/hide toggle?

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky-footer

my main container div can be refreshed, so its content is being hide/shown. When my container div is hide, my footer shoots up.

the html structure looks like the following:

Note that i already tried this:

And it doesn't seem to work, the footer div will still shoot up when the container div is hidden.

Nor can i set a height on the container div because i want the content div height to stretch 100%.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may get more help if you accept some answers to your older questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) is excellent for keeping the footer where it should be.

Comment: Excellent, glad you could use it.

Answer (score 8):

Use this css:

```
#yourdiv {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
}
```

This will make it stick to the bottom :)

Comment: problem is if you have text align center it will not work with this :(